# How to implement a macro for normal ordering of operators?

Tags: spacing, macros

I am looking to typeset the normal ordering symbols `:O:` commonly used in quantum field theory in a way that makes them easily discernible from regular colons, especially the 'defined as' symbol `:=`. Has anybody come across a good `LaTeX` implementation for such a command which always adds the right amount of white space before and after each `:`?

**Update**

In my context, egreg's solution `\newcommand{\normord}[1]{:\mathrel{#1}:}` appears as follows:

[image]

A (rather inelegant) combination of Bernard's and egreg's answer `\newcommand{\normord}[1]{{:}\!\mathrel{#1}\!{:}}` produces

[image]

which I don't think looks great but might the best output I achieved yet.

Comment: `:\mathrel{O}:`? Can you point to some place where the thing can be seen?

Comment: Or may be `$\colon\mathop{O}\colon$`?. ‘Defined as’ is simply `coloneqq` with the `mathtools` package.

Comment: @egreg Well, you can see the notation in use in the [Wikipedia entry for normal ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_order). However, this article lacks a cohesive implementation. Note how in the section 'Notation' normal ordering is written as `\mathopen{:}\hat{O}\mathclose{:}` whereas in 'Single Bosons - Examples' it is simply `:\hat{b}^\dagger\,\hat{b}:`.

Comment: @PacificOrion I saw it and found no clue, as every appearance is different form any other.

Comment: Maybe `:\mathrel{#1}\colon`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Being an ordering, it should be a relation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\normord}[1]{:\mathrel{#1}:}

\begin{document}
$X \normord{\hat{O}} Y$

$X \normord{\hat{b}^{\dag}\hat{b}} Y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can slightly raise the colons using `\vcentcolon`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\normord}[1]{\vcentcolon\mathrel{#1}\vcentcolon}
\providecommand{\vcentcolon}{\mathrel{\mathop{:}}}

\begin{document}
$X \normord{\hat{O}} Y$                             

$X \normord{\hat{b}^{\dag}\hat{b}} Y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

I use `\providecommand` so that if you load `mathtools` (before those definitions, of course), the definition would be ignored (`mathtools` defines `\vcentcolon` in that precise way).

Can we raise the colon more than this? Of course we can, but it's not necessarily a good idea.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\normord}[1]{\xcentcolon\mathrel{#1}\xcentcolon}
\newcommand{\xcentcolon}{%
  \mathrel{\vbox{\hbox{$:$}\kern.2ex}}%
}

\begin{document}
$X \normord{\hat{O}} Y$

$X \normord{\hat{b}^{\dag}\hat{b}} Y$

$X \normord{a} Y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to add space in the middle, do it!

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\normord}[1]{:\mathrel{\mkern2mu #1 \mkern2mu}:}

\begin{document}
$X \normord{\hat{O}} Y$

$X \normord{\hat{b}^{\dag}\hat{b}} Y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let's take as example exercise 9.3 of ['Modern Quantum Field Theory' by Thomas Banks](http://web.phys.ntnu.no/~mika/banks.pdf), page 204; here is an extract from the original

[image]

Here is my emulation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\normord}[1]{%
  :\mathrel{\mspace{2mu}#1\mspace{2mu}}:%
}

\begin{document}
$\langle T :\phi^4(x)::\phi^4(x): \phi(y_1)\dots\phi(y_n)\rangle$.

$\langle T \normord{\phi^4(x)} \normord{\phi^4(x)} \phi(y_1)\dots\phi(y_n)\rangle$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

It's quite evident that the book has been typeset using the first way: no special symbol (the spacing is clearly from considering `:` a math relation). I find the second way much less distracting.

A different approach would be considering it just as an ordinary symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\normord}[1]{%
  {:\mathrel{\mspace{1mu}#1\mspace{1mu}}:}%
}

\begin{document}
$\langle T \normord{\phi^4(x)} \normord{\phi^4(x)} \phi(y_1)\dots\phi(y_n)\rangle$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. So far I had been using `\newcommand{\normorder}[1]{\mathop{:} #1 \mathop{:}}` but I like your spacing better. In the meantime I discovered something else that bothered me. When writing normal ordering on paper, I (rightly or wrongly) always slightly raised the colons. To me regular colons appear too low to really _enclose_ the operators between them. Is there a way to raise them by, say `0.2ex`? `\raisebox{0.2ex}{:}` doesn't work since it adds white space left and right.

Comment: Concerning your updated answer: The raise is hardly noticeable. Is there something a little more 'intent' than `\vcentcolon`?

Comment: @PacificOrion I added the trick, but also an example of why I'd not use it. In my opinion, simple unraised colons are the best.

Comment: Good point, your last example. Perhaps you're right and unraised colons it should be.

Comment: @PacificOrion You can choose; if all your symbols between the colons are high, then raising the colons can be justified. In any case, you just change the definition of `\normord`, so you can ensure uniformity.

Comment: Combining your answer with Bernard's and some rough patching actually gave me the most desirable output yet. Compare the two images I added to my question.

Comment: @PacificOrion I added a less barbaric way to add space around the middle operator.

Comment: @egreg Despite being called "ordering", normal ordering is not a relation.  I'd say the colons behave more like brackets (say, `\lfloor` and `\rfloor`).  I have to admit though that I don't know what to suggest as the best choice of spacing.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch My physics is rather low level; possibly `\mathinner` around the whole thing could be better?

Comment: Not sure.  Perhaps `\mathopen{:}\mathinner{#1}\mathclose{:}` if that makes sense?  Basically, it should be the same as what you would suggest for brackets, and my typographical sense is lacking.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch There would be no space on the left and right of the whole thing. Can you point to some textbook page where the notation is used?

Comment: Ah, you're right, and without spaces, the notation would be confusing (e.g. in :φ::φ:=:φ²:+…).  Your implementation gives better results.  I don't have a textbook at hand right now, sorry. (well, I do, but no scanner)

Comment: @egreg Well, you can check out the notation in its natural environment in my [QFT lecture notes](http://www.thphys.uni-heidelberg.de/~weigand/QFT2-14/SkriptQFT2.pdf). Normal ordering is introduced on p. 59. However, I think this scrip adds too much white space between operators and the normal ordering symbols.

Comment: @PacificOrion Sorry, but I meant some printed book from an “independent” source.

Comment: @egreg You mean printed on paper? Why do you need that? To be clear, I did not type these notes. They come from my professor.

Comment: @PacificOrion I would like to see how some publisher typeset the symbols; selfproduced notes are not fully reliable, as they reflect just your professor's idea.

Comment: @egreg In that case you could consult one of many good books on QFT. A pdf of 'Modern Quantum Field Theory' by Thomas Banks can be viewed [here](http://web.phys.ntnu.no/~mika/banks.pdf). He talks about normal ordering on p. 141.
Interestingly, Peskin and Schröder in their ‘[An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory](http://tinyurl.com/mgbg22y)‘ introduce normal ordering as an operator `N(O)` (on p. 88) analogous to the time ordering operator `T(O)` (which would have been my first idea of how to write this operation if I had introduced it).

Comment: The second way, i.e. `$\langle T \normord{\phi^4(x)} \normord{\phi^4(x)} \phi(y_1)\dots\phi(y_n)\rangle$.
\end{document}` has the problem that it does not separate the colon from other math symbols such as `=`. This can cause confusion and if in doubt, requires the reader to go back to the beginning of an expression and count the number of 'opened' and 'closed' colons.

Comment: This answer is very weird: the very first sentence, «Being an ordering, it should be a relation» assumes that it is an ordering, and it isn't!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I’m not sure to understand what you’re objecting to. According to the posted image, the symbol should be treated as a binary relation.

Comment: @egreg I think Alvarez's objection is that the normal ordering is not a "relation" (it's not like "equals" or "congruence"), it's instead more like parentheses or brackets...I think the TeX-nical term is, it's a "left opening" and "right opening" wrapped around an expression.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution, which is perhaps intuitive, is to treat the colons like a delimiter:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{minimal}
\usepackage[paperwidth=3in,paperheight=1in]{geometry}

\newcommand\normalorder[1]{\mathopen{:}#1\mathclose{:}}

\begin{document}

\[ \normalorder{ \hat b^\dagger\hat b} = \hat b^\dagger \hat b \]%

\[\langle T \normalorder{\phi^4(x)} \normalorder{\phi^4(x)} \phi(y_1)\dots\phi(y_n)\rangle\]


\end{document}
```

This has the disadvantage of spacing between the end of the normal ordering operator and the next expression, if it's not a binary operator or something similar.

[image]

## Alternatives Used in the Literature

Just browsing the source for articles from arxiv can give a number of suggestive alternatives.

For an alternative definition, [arXiv:physics/0212061](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0212061) uses `\newcommand{\n}[1]{{:}\, #1 {:} }` for normal ordering, which gives a little more space, and may be more aesthetically pleasing.

A more idiosyncratic choice may be found in [arXiv:hep-th/9308151](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9308151) using something like `\newcommand\Ord{_\times^\times}` to delimit normally ordered products with small `\times` colons, but this is a kludge.

A similar kludge, though more aesthetically pleasing, may be found in [arXiv:math/9909178](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9909178) using `\newcommand{\nordbullet}{\mbox{\tiny ${\bullet\atop\bullet}$}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcommand\normalorder[1]{{:}\mkern1mu#1\mkern1.6mu{:}}

\begin{document}

\[ \normalorder{ \hat b^\dagger\hat b} = \hat b^\dagger \hat b \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think I quite understand your example. Do any of the used package serve a purpose?

Comment: No real purpose here. It's only a template I use for my examples — in case I need accented letters or one of the amsmath environments. Putting a colon between brackets makes it an ordinary character, not a punctuation sign, and \mkern adds some kerning in math mode.