# Normal ordering macro in LyX

Tags: macros, errors, lyx

I want to define a macro for the normal ordering of operators as done [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214347/how-to-implement-a-macro-for-normal-ordering-of-operators).

The LaTeX code produced by LyX for this macro is:

```
\global\long\def\norder#1{\vcentcolon#1\vcentcolon}
```

However, when I invoke it:

```
$\norder{\hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger}}$
```

it gives an error:

*...ven by $\norder{\hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger}}
                                                  $
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.*

I don't understand why it gives the error. I have more macros in the document and they work perfectly. `amsmath` and `amssimb` are loaded through LyX's "Math Options" (and I have checked that I can use commands such as `\mathbb` inside macros). Looks like the problem is the `\vcentcolon` command but I don't see why or how to fix it. 
Thank you!

PS. This is what I have before the `begin{document}` in the LaTeX source generated by LyX.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{esint}
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{braket}
\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\ventcolon` has not been defined. Load the package `mathtools`; you can load it instead of `amsmath`. Moreover, wrap the stuff between the colons into a `\mathrel` command to improve the spacing.

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\norder[1]{\vcentcolon\mathrel{#1}\vcentcolon}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\norder[1]{\vcentcolon\mathrel{#1}\vcentcolon}
\begin{document}
$A \norder{\hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger}} B$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding `mathtools` solved the issue. Thanks!